# Html Drag and Drop using jQuery w/out Draggable

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Could anyone post a minimalistic example of drag'n'drop imeplementation using jQuery without using draggable behavior? On my understanding it shouldn't be much longer than 10 lines.

I've the following html:

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
  <div id="draggable" style="width:10px; height:10px; background-color:blue;" />
</div>
```

I want to make a blue squre draggable so.

I've got my implementation working, but it looks rather monstrous, so I 'd like to get a touch of class from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$('#draggable').on('mousedown', function (evt) {
  var offset = {x: evt.offsetX || evt.originalEvent.layerX, y: evt.offsetY || evt.originalEvent.layerY};

  // bind mousemove only if dragging is actually happening
  $(document).on({
    // delegate the mousemove event to the draggable element
    'mousemove.drag': $.proxy(function(evt) {
      $(this).css({left: evt.pageX - offset.x, top: evt.pageY - offset.y});
    }, this),

    // unbind namespaced events on mouseup
    'mouseup.drag': function (evt) {
      $(document).off('.drag');
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sXahK/6/

Comment: love the approach but it doesn't work in FF using jQuery 1.7.1:( It doesn't work in the fiddler niether.

Comment: Confirmed works in Chrome. I'm so not up date with JS - can't see how you hide the actual mouse pointer - can I have it visible at all times?

Comment: @Dmitry The FF bug comes from the offsetX/Y, I'll change that. About the cursor, it's not hidden, just not visible because of the background-color ;)

Comment: thanks for that. Could it be fixed for FF so? Love the technique all the way.

Comment: Works in FF now! Doesn't behave correctly after the first drop. Drag it then drop then drag again - it won't drag it no more. I've marked it as answer, could you fix it up for me please?

Comment: @Dmitry Solved the FF problem (which by the way is a really strange one) be returning false (stopping the event bubbling). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "without Draggable" you mean without jQuery UI. You could do something like this:

```
var dragging = false;
$("#draggable").mousedown(function() {
   dragging = true; 
}).mouseup(function() {
   dragging = false; 
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(dragging) {
        $("#draggable").css({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});  
    } 
});
```

It's far from perfect but it should be enough to get you started. It won't constrain the dragging to the container for example.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EjcnA/).

Comment: try drag and release - and then drag again. it creates an unwanted sticky draggable effect. Also for large draggables (change draggable size to 50 by 50) it looks ugly when drag operation doesn't respect the actual drag start posistion.

Comment: @Dmitry - As I said in the answer, it wasn't meant to be perfect, just a basic starting point that the OP could use to get going.