# Html 5 Drag and Drop using jQuery w/out Draggable with WebKit browsers support

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, touch

This is a continuation of:

[Html Drag and Drop using jQuery w/out Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805403/html-drag-and-drop-using-jquery-w-out-draggable/8805706#comment10990191_8805706)

What's the right way of implemetning Drag and Drop with Mobile Browsers support (primarily WebKit) - I believe touch events were introduced in Html5 otherwise please correct me.

Ideally I'm looking for some sort of a JS EventHandlerFactory which will create event handlers on demand based upon device type as opposed to creating conditional blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that mobile webkit intercepts the touch events and assumes you want to pan the page.

Check the docs here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Mobile webkit seems to pick up these events okay.